# Azure App Configuration or Azure KeyVault - trigger new build on changed value

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, configurationmanager

I'm using Azure App Configuration and Azure Key Vault to get values for my applications during build in Azure DevOps.

Is it possible, when I change any value inside Azure App Configuration and/or Azure Key Vault, get some trigger notification (like when I make a commit in the repository) to rebuild pipeline with new values? 
Is it possible to implement this with Azure App Configuration and Azure Key Vault ?

Comment: You can use webhook that will trigger new build when the secret\key has changed. But, why would you like to do that?

Comment: Because I need to rebuild all my applications with new values

Comment: Why aren't you getting those values are runtime instead? That's the intent behind both services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Azure Event Grid and react to events when there's a change on key vault.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/event-grid-tutorial

For the opposite, there's no event grid integration yet. I recommend you perform those changes only through Azure Devops, then you can add a new task to also change Key Vault.

Comment: ps: keep an eye on this repo: https://github.com/SeanFeldman/azure-events-wishlist/issues/124